# Generics factory in Java

Tags: java, generics

Can anybody post the Java version of this VB.NET code?

```
    Public Function FetchDoc(Of T As {New, IRepoDocument})(ByVal docId As String) As IRepoDocument Implements IDocRepository.FetchDoc

        Dim repoDoc As New T

        //some code to init repoDoc

        Return repoDoc

    End Function
```

This function accepts and create a instance of any class implementing `IRepoDocument` and has a no-argument constructor.

The only way I found is:

```
public <T extends IRepoDocument> IRepoDocument FetchDoc(String idDoc, Class<T> clazz)
    throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException 
{
  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

But I want to suppress `Class<T> clazz` as input parameter.

Comment: So you want to search the ClassLoader for any class that implements IRepoDocument and instantiate it?

Comment: How do you want it to work out which class you actually want?

Comment: There is no way to do that without the Class argument in Java.

Comment: So, is the Java code in my post the best way to do the same it's done in the vb.net code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an instance in Java without a `Class` instance to specify what class the instance is of -- except for anonymous classes (see below). You can get that class instance as a parameter, or hide it under a rock, or fish it out of the ocean, but you have to have it *at runtime*. The classes associated with the generics are removed by type erasure and just aren't there.

I don't know VB.NET from stringbeans, but you might, in some cases, be looking for an anonymous class.

```
new IRepoDocument() { ......fill in code };
```

In this case, there's be no `<T>` at all, the return type would just be IRepoDocument.

Comment: No, it's simple: if you don't pass in the type-tag argument, there is no way for that method to find out what type you want instantiated. It's not about following any rules of conduct.

Comment: I was thinking about the common case in which the Class<T> argument is used to avoid a cast, not for newInstance. Fixed.

Comment: So, is the Java code in my post the best way to do the same it's done in the vb.net code?

Comment: I have no idea how VB.net chooses a class for you, so I can't advise.

Comment: I'm not asking about the best way in VB.NET, asking about the best way in Java. Thanks anyway.